# What is the best practices to implement caching layer?

Tags: caching, redis

I'm going to use Redis as a cache service.
What is the best practices to access the caching service?
Through a service/API or in-memory component?
I'm not sure I want to have access to the DB from all the services.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All your questions depends on topology and/or architecture of your system. I don't think that you would provide a service on separated computer if your application resided completely on one computer.

But suppose you have distributed app.

In this case it makes sense to do caching using separated service on separated node. It's same as within OOP, you can simple encapsulate data also in cache. Other services depends on your cache, not directly on Redis - you can decide to change redis for something else. Another advantage of caching service is that you can cache data in memory depending on throughput and fetches data from redis time to time. Note that you can simple buy a server having a lot of RAM, e.g. 192gb, because caching service needs a memory more than anything else.